# mktexlsr fails to build package index

Tags: packages, texlive, installing

I just installed Linux Mint 17 on a new laptop and attempted to install `texlive` from the command line in the usual way

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-base texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-base
$ sudo mktexlsr
```

So far so good. Then I added (via USB drive) some extra custom and specialized packages that I had in my previous laptop, ran `mktexlsr` again, and problems began. If I write

```
\usepackage{mycustompackage}
```

and run `latex <filename>` I get an error message to the effect that `mycustompackage` cannot be found. This is a `mktexlsr` problem, because specifying the full path

```
\usepackage{/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/custom/mycustompackage}
```

makes everything run smoothly.

I have the lingering feeling that I'm missing something really obvious here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Where did you add your own packages? $HOME/.texlive2015? $TEXINPUTS? Did you specify the directory for `mktexlsr` or what does $TEXMFDBS say?

Comment: I added my packages to `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/custom/` which is the same directory they used to live in in my previous laptop. Also, I had never had problems with `mktexlsr` finding new packages, whether custom or downloaded from ctan or other sources.

Comment: You shouldn't add packages in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`, but rather in `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/custom` (better yet use `$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/custom`, which will do the right thing. This is for all users; for your personal packages, use `TEXMFHOME` (and this doesn't require `mktexlsr`).